# How to delete multiple rows with 2 columns as composite primary key in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named **ProductLog** `(RequestID, Date, Product, Price)`. Here `RequestID` and `Product` is composite primary key.

Now there is a cleaning tool which cleans the product after some days. Priviously the cleaning was straight cut. If Date was less than 15 days then delete it. Now some situation comes like - suppose there is a product which logs 18 days back. Now if we delete data less that 15 days then it will delete that product. Every product data should be there cause it is used for some monitoring purpose. Now deletion requirement changed.

Choose a product.

- If the product has record within 15 days then keep 15 days data and
  delete remaining.
- If the product record is not within 15 days then don't delete the data.

Now I am trying to use query like

```
select RequestID, Product from ProductLog where Date < '201505161505'
EXCEPT
select RequestID, Product from ProductLog where Product not in (
    select distinct Product  from ProductLog where Date >  '201505161505' 
)
```

I am able to select the data which should be deleted. Now I have to delete it. As `RequestID` and `Product` is a composite primary key, I can't use `IN` for deletion. Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `Exists` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking to write a delete statement based on your query above, I would use `EXISTS` query to handle both columns (`RequestID` and `Product`) at the same time.

```
DELETE
FROM ProductLog
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT RequestID
                ,Product
            FROM ProductLog
            WHERE DATE < '201505161505'

            EXCEPT

            SELECT RequestID
                ,Product
            FROM ProductLog p
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM ProductLog p1
                    WHERE p.product = p1.product
                        AND DATE > '201505161505'
                    )
            ) t
        WHERE t.RequestID = ProductLog.RequestID
            AND t.Product = ProductLog.Product
        );
```

Also, I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` in your subquery.

> The most important thing to note about NOT EXISTS and NOT IN is that,
>   unlike EXISTS and IN, they are not equivalent in all cases.
>   Specifically, when NULLs are involved they will return different
>   results. To be totally specific, when the subquery returns even one
>   null, NOT IN will not match any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add the number of days to keep to the product table. Then:

```
delete from ProductLog
from ProductLog pl
inner join Product p on p.ProductId = pl.ProductId
and pl.Date > DateAdd(day, - p.NumberOfDaysToKeep, getdate());
```